# Cannot await Task<MyObject>

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I am unable to figure out why the following code keeps throwing the 'Cannot await' error...

I have a feeling I may be getting the wrong end of the stick with regards to implementing an asynchronous API action. Can anyone direct  me on where I am going wrong?

**API action:**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    var getAnimal = animalManager.Get(id);

    var animal = await getAnimal;

    return Ok(animal);
}
```

**Manager/Service method:**

```
public async Task<Animal> Get(int id)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => { return animalRepository.Get(id); });     
}
```

**Repository method (Synchronous):**

```
public Animal Get(int id)
{
    var animal = dbSet.Find(id);

    if (animal == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Animal");
    }

    return animal;
}
```

Comment: Just a code style note: the service method (or any `async` method in general should have an `Async` suffix, so it should be named `GetAsync`.

Comment: At which `await` do you get this error. At first look all seems fine (except that `ArgumentNullException` seems the wrong error if you did not find a result).

Comment: Is it compile or runtime error?
Have you tried to use async version of DbSet, f.e. `FindAsync()`?

Comment: You should refactor to go async all the way down. You should not use `Task.Run` in asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `dbSet.Find`, use [`dbSet.FindAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.findasync(v=vs.113).aspx). Consider the following:

**Repo**

```
public Task<Animal> GetAsync(int id)
{
    return dbSet.FindAsync(id);
}
```

**Service**

```
public Task<Animal> GetAsync(int id)
{
    return animalRepository.GetAsync(id);;     
}
```

**API**

Then your source code in the API will work as you'd expect. You could simplify it a little by awaiting the call instead of taking on the `Task<Animal>` variable, and yield your animal.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    var animal = await animalManager.GetAsync(id);

    return Ok(animal);
}
```

Additionally, your repo and service layer code can easily return just the `Task` that represents the asynchronous operation rather than awaiting it. Take advantage of the existing APIs, specifically in **EF**. This is preferred over manually invocations of `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`.